# How to return strings to a custom ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How would I go about inserting this code into a ListView in android?

```
  List<YouTubeVideo> videos = ym.retrieveVideos(textQuery, maxResults, filter, timeout);

        for (YouTubeVideo youtubeVideo : videos) {
            System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getWebPlayerUrl());
            System.out.println("Thumbnails");
            for (String thumbnail : youtubeVideo.getThumbnails()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + thumbnail);
            }
            System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getEmbeddedWebPlayerUrl());
            System.out.println("************************************");         }
        }

}
```

Would I create a custom adapter and use getView()? If so how would it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would create a custom adapter and use getView().  Here is some sample code for a row layout with a TextView and an ImageView:

```
private static class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context         context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater  mInflater;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) 
    {
        this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override       
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);                                
        } 

        Item item = items.get(position);

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data_item);
        tv.setText(item.getItem());

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: SO how would it look with the code i have above? And would it be BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Your code above could become a method that is used to populate the ArrayList<YouTubeVideo> in your case -- ArrayList<Item> in my code.  You can do this in the onCreate method.  I would start with this to get up to speed then experiment with getting data in the background can calling notifyDataSetChanged when the List data structure is updated.  I've been using BaseAdapter in my code but you could switch it ArrayAdapter and the code would be similar.